# CSS change positions using media queries

Tags: html, css, position

Hi can please someone help me I'm breaking my brain trying to change a position of a div from absolute to `static(default)` I need that when the page reduce to `800px` the `div(absolute)` that is above another `div(relative)` change his position to stack below of the `div(relative)` but the problem is that  I can't change some of the code because I showing a slide and this slide maintain an `aspect ratio 16:9` of the pictures that's why I use a `top-padding 52.5` to always maintain this aspect ratio and the pictures maint his original aspect I just need that the dive that has the text above the pictures stacks below right where the picture ends or the div of the picture ends

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navi{
  background:yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.jumbo{
  background:grey;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  margin-top:20px;
}


.slideshow{
  background:green;
  width:100%;


}
.slide-image-wrap{
  width:100%;


  box-sizing: border-box;


}
.mySlides {

  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;


  }

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;


}
#tata .slide-image-wrap .mySlides{

  position: relative;
  height:0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

}

#tata img{

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}


.slide-text-wrap{
  height: 100px;
  width:500px;
  background:blue;
  position: absolute;

  bottom:20%;
  right: 6%;
  color:orange;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;

}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: right:   ;
}
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}




@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {




}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .slide-text-wrap{
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0%;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
  width: 450px;
}


}
```

Answer (score -1):

For responsive media query (**This works when the screen maximum with less than 800px**)

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
     .yourClassName{
       //style goes here
     }
}
```

Visit to refer the css flex box https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e02dl66PYo?